# VS2010 highlight references only on doubleclick

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to make C# code editor in VS2010 only highlight word references when a word is doubleclicked, like e.g. MetalScroll, not always whenever the cursor is on a word?

Maybe there are some extensions that could do it? Is it even possible to affect this area of VS with an extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/04/14/the-best-of-visual-studio-2010-how-to-use-reference-highlighting.aspx

You could maybe use the information here to write a macro to enable/disable highlighting on demand (though it won't work on a double click)

Comment: This link unfortunately does not answer the question.